# CS0311 There is no implicit reference conversion on constrained generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to write a [constrained generic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) but I can't get it to compile.  The compiler doesn't seem to see the inherited references.

[LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) Script:

```
// usage
void Main()
{
    //CS0311 The type 'UserQuery.SomeEntityRepo' cannot be used as 
    //type parameter 'T' in the generic type 
    //or method 'UserQuery.Problem.Blah<T>()'. 
    //There is no implicit reference conversion from 'UserQuery.SomeEntityRepo' 
    //to 'UserQuery.IEntityRepo<UserQuery.Entity>'.
    SomeHelper.Blah<SomeEntityRepo>();
}
```

```
// generic method definition
class SomeHelper
{
    internal static Task Blah<T>() where T : IEntityRepo<Entity>
    {
        return GetFromDIContainer<T>()
            .DoSomething();
    }
}
```

```
// base definitions
class Entity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

interface IEntityRepo<T> where T : Entity
{
    Task DoSomething();
} 

class EntityRepo<T> where T : Entity
{
    Task DoSomething()
    { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

```
// inheritance definitions
class SomeEntity : Entity { }

class SomeEntityRepo : EntityRepo<SomeEntity> { }
```

`SomeEntityRepo` implements `IEntityRepo<SomeEntity>` & `SomeEntity` inherits from `Entity`.  Seems related to [covariance & contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) ‍♂️.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly related to covariance. `IEntityRepo<T>` is not covariant, and so you can't pretend that an `IEntityRepo<SomeEntity>` is actually an `IEntityRepo<Entity>` (if the compiler let you do that, and `IEntityRepo<T>` had a method to put objects into the repo, then you would be able to put *any* `Entity` into an `IEntityRepo<SomeEntity>`, and not just `SomeEntity` instances, which would obviously be broken). If your repo is covariant, and only has methods to take `T`'s *out* of the repo (and not put them in), then mark it as covariant: `IEntityRepo<out T> where T : Entity`

Comment: Well first off you're implementing methods in `IEntityRepo<T>`, which is not correct. Only put the method signature in the interface, then fully implement it in `SomeEntityRepo`.

Comment: Hi @IsaacCorbrey - I've update my example (trying to boil it down to the simplest sample can be tricky!)

Comment: Hi @canton7 - I've updated the sample to try to simplify it some more.  Not sure how I can use `out` in this simplified example.  [Variance in delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates) ?

Comment: In your latest example, `EntityRepo` doesn't inherit from `IEntityRepo`. Fix that, and the fact that `EntityRepo.DoSomething` needs to be public, and it compiles just fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/75mslg

Comment: @canton7 - fixed, thanks! 

Comment: So, what's your question? Your example code compiles fine, and doesn't raise the error you claim it does

Comment: @canton7 - sorry, I *only* saw the first part of your comment somehow.  It does compile after that.  So that's not good example as that's not my problem.  Reverting...

Comment: This is probably what you're after: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QVYzZ1 . And the explanation is the same one I gave an hour ago

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218917/discussion-between-spottedmahn-and-canton7).